# How can I count children of container? .children().length return 0

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to count all child elements of container. Elements are of different type. Unfortunately this code return "0". What did I wrong?

```js
var count = $(".slide-container").children().length;
alert(count);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="slide-container">
  <p>SLIDE 1</p>
  <article>SLIDE 2</article>
  <div>SLIDE 3</div>
  <img src="img/gallery/some.jpg" />
</div>
```

Comment: You need to put your code in a document.ready() handler or run it at the end of the page. The code itself is fine, you're just running it too early. https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/jh4970x4/

Comment: ^^what he said ^^

Comment: Now i'm confused :)

Thanks :)

Comment: The documentation always helps: https://learn.jquery.com/about-jquery/how-jquery-works/

Comment: Basically you're trying to count the elements before they're available to be counted.  The above comments give ways to delay your code running until after the DOM is ready (when the elements are available to be counted).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your DOM has not been created before you call your variable `count`

Please use `($document).on("ready")` function :

```
   <script>
    $(document).on('ready',function(){
       var count = $(".slide-container").children().length;

       alert(count);
    });
</script>
<div class="slide-container">

        <p>SLIDE 1</p>

        <article>SLIDE 2</article>

        <div>SLIDE 3</div>

        <img src="img/gallery/some.jpg" />

    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [`$(document).ready()`](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) to run the script when the DOM is finished loading. Currently it runs before it's finished loading everything on the page.

```js
//use $(document).ready() to run the script when the DOM is loaded
$(document).ready(function() {
  var count = $(".slide-container").children().length;
  alert(count);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="slide-container">
  <p>SLIDE 1</p>
  <article>SLIDE 2</article>
  <div>SLIDE 3</div>
  <img src="img/gallery/some.jpg" />
</div>
```